# Unit Testing ViewModel + Coroutine + LiveData

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I have a problem testing the following ViewModel with coroutines. Even though I inject a TestCoroutineDispatcher() in the viewModel for testing and runs the code inside a runBlocking block the call to fetchInitialData seems to be executed on another thread and my test fails due to assertion being made before fetchInitialData method completes

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    private val repository: MyRepository
) : ViewModel() {

fun fetchInitialData() {
    viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
        _loading.postValue(true)
        // do some heavy work
        _loading.postValue(false)
        _myList.postValue(result)
    }
}
```

My test is as follow:

```
@Test
fun myTest() runBlocking {
    server.mockJsonResponse("a-json-response.json")
    viewModel = MyViewModel(
        testCoroutineDispatcher,
        MyRepository(service)
    )
    viewModel.fetchInitialData() // this block doesn't stop it's asynchronous
    // my assertions comes here
}
```

Comment: Is your test suite using [InstantTaskExecutorRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/arch/core/executor/testing/InstantTaskExecutorRule)?

Comment: Yes, it's using InstantTaskExecutorRule() for LiveData and TestCoroutineDispatcher(). I'm also using Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatchers) on ```@Before``` and Dispatchers.resetMain on ```@After```

Comment: Can you post your assertions?

Answer (score 0):

As you are posting value in liveData you need to add this line on your TestFile

```
 @get:Rule
 var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

After this if it still doesn't work add this line of code before your assert :

```
testDispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()
```